# The LDS consider God the Father the ultimate creator and they teach that Jesus Christ is the creator. Which of these two Gods is the creator?

Tags: lds, isaiah, god-the-father

The LDS Church has a teaching that [God the Father is the "ultimate Creator"](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/god-the-father?lang=eng)

The following has Jesus Christ being the creator: https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1988/08/i-have-a-question/why-do-latter-day-saints-believe-that-jesus-christ-was-jehovah-of-the-old-testament?lang=eng

So based on the LDS understanding of following passages from the book of Isaiah we read the following.

> Thus says the Lord your Redeemer, and the one who formed you from the womb, I, the Lord am the maker of all things, Stretching out the heavens BY MYSELF, And spreading out the earth ALL ALONE.
>
> Isaiah 44:24, NASB (Emphasis added)

and

> For thus says the Lord who created the heavens (He is the God who formed the earth and made it, He established it and did not create it a waste place, but formed it to be inhabited). I AM THE LORD AND THERE IS NONE ELSE.
>
> Isaiah 45:18, NASB (Emphasis added)

Do Latter-day Saints believe the Father or the Son created the heavens and spread out the earth all alone? And depending on that answer, is it the Father or the Son who states, "I am the Lord God and there is none else"?

Comment: Please only leave comments to specifically help improve the question.  @Mrbond, please only indirectly "engage theological innovators", this site is not designed as a sounding board for any branch of Christianity (even the True One)

Comment: @PeterTurner I edited my question to be more focused.

Comment: FWIW on edits to the title, I'm not disputing that Latter-day Saints believe more than one God exists, but I found the possessive "their" or "your" gods to be misleading. I appreciate the compromise on the title. (though if I were writing the question I would capitalize the word "gods" =)  )

Answer (score 3):

Jesus Christ created the earth under the direction of Heavenly Father ([source](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/creation?lang=eng)). As an analogy, I think of Heavenly Father as the architect and Jesus Christ as the builder.

This apparently contradicts the verses you quote from Isaiah, where the Lord asserts that He created the earth all alone. The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints identifies Jehovah as Jesus Christ ([source](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/the-living-christ-the-testimony-of-the-apostles/the-living-christ-the-testimony-of-the-apostles?lang=eng)), so I would suggest that the speaker in the verses you linked was Jesus Christ. However, I reconcile the contradiction by considering Jehovah to be speaking on behalf of the Godhead as a single unit. The scriptures (both the Bible and the Book of Mormon) teach that the Father, the Son and the Holy Ghost are one (see for example, 3 Nephi 11:36). We understand this to mean that the Father, the Son and the Holy Ghost are completely unified in mission & intent. Compare to:

- God's command for husband & wife to be one in Genesis 2
- Jesus' prayer that His disciples would be one in John 17
- Paul's declaration that he and Apollos were one in 1 Corinthians 3

Imperfect mortals are taught to emulate the perfect example given by God. This is a discussion of alignment of the will & purpose, not an alignment of substance.

Therefore it makes sense to us for Jesus Christ to speak of the Godhead as One.

Comment: I added some examples and a couple edits. If you don't like them I can roll them back.